# Find exponent of float in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Im stuck on a certain part of my Assembly homework.

Im reading in floating point values and doing a square root function via Newtons method. Ive got the formula working fine, but having trouble extracting the exponent from a floating point number. (For my initial guess in the loop)

I think im supposed to use a AND mask on the float or some sort of shift left operation, but all the info im finding online is for dealing with ints.

Im not new to assembly, but new to MIPS so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: You can treat the 32-bit floating point number as if it were a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Am I able to shift left or right the floating point registers? Or do I need to copy them to an int register to modulate them?

Comment: The instruction set reference will tell you if such an instruction exists. Since it's for homework I'm guessing it's a restricted subset anyway, so it shouldn't take long to figure out. Anyhow, if you know how to do it by copying them to an integer register it would just be an optimization anyway.

Comment: If I copy it to a int register and shift correctly, I should be left with the exponent. Is this what youre getting at?

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker to just try it? But yes, with proper shifting you should be left with the [exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding).

Comment: Sorry, im trying this at the same time, im about an hour into this language so its all very new. The way floats and ints are addressed are confusing me. I see how if I could shift left and right the correct bits from the float, I can get the correct exponent. But I cant seem to copy from the float register to a save register without converting to an int value (which I dont want).

What would be the correct command to dump all the data without conversion to a workable register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize:

- You have a 32-bit single precision floating point number in a floating point register.
- You want to manipulate it as if it were a 32-bit integer.
- You can only manipulate integer values in the normal registers.
- If you move directly from a floating point register to a normal register it gets converted.

It seems like you can't get it directly from a floating point register. How would you normally get a value into a register?

Comment: I really have no clue how I would do this, I can see that you are trying to help subtly, but I simply dont know what I would do next.

Comment: You can load an integer from memory with `LW` to a "normal" register and store it back with `SW`. I assume you can also load and store floating point numbers (unmodified!) from memory, right?

Comment: Ah ok, that makes so much more sense. I dont think ive had enough seat time to get used to the way things are passed. I think I can take it from here. Thank You so much for your help.